# Using a Submit Button to add items to a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am still a student and have very little experience managing a database (close to none).  So what I am stuck on trying to figure out is I have "followers" who select Menu Items from a Menu on a restaurants page (using check boxes and a submit button).  I have the model configured to where the followers have an array of MenuItems in their table, but I am having trouble with getting the coding right for it to work where the submit button adds those menu items to the followers array.

Here is the action method I have so far:

```
    public ActionResult AddMenuItems(int MenuItemID)
    {
    //  Need to run through array of MEnuItem ID's and add them to the Followers LIst of MEnuItems


        foreach (var menuItem in Model.MenuItems)//Getting an error here because it can't call Model.MenuItems, not sure how to properly get there....
        {
            Model.MenuItems menuItem = new Model.MenuItems();  
            menuItem.menuItemID = menuItem.Key;
            if (menuItem.key == MenuItemID) 
            { 
                Follower.Add(menuItem); 
            }

        }

    }
```

Am I heading in the right direction?  Can anyone post pseudocode to lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I'd refer you to [Microsoft's set of Entity Framework tutorials](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). It doesn't seem that you really understand how to properly set up entities/context.

Next, your code here is contradictory. You talk about having an array of menu item ids, but your action merely takes a single id. If you truly want to post multiple ids, then you need to bind to a `List<int>` or similar, not `int`.

Assuming you actually should have a list of ids, then generally speaking, you want to use those ids to select the menu items from the database, and then add those to the collection on `Follower` that holds menu items:

```
db.MenuItems.Where(m => menuItemIds.Contains(m.Id)).ToList()
    .ForEach(m => follower.MenuItems.Add(m));
```

When editing existing selections, you need to be more careful, however, as running the above code will actually make Entity Framework attempt to readd already existing menu items. Instead, you first need to remove items that have been deselected, and then add only items that are new. Since this is a many-to-many, existing items require no updates.

```
// Remove deselected menu items
follower.MenuItems.Where(m => !menuItemIds.Contains(m.Id)).ToList()
    .ForEach(m => follower.MenuItems.Remove(m));

// Add newly selected menu items
var existingMenuItemIds = follower.MenuItems.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
db.MenuItems.Where(m => menuItemIds.Except(existingMenuItemIds).Contains(m.Id)).ToList()
    .ForEach(m => follower.MenuItems.Add(m));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for thank you for the link to the tutorials and the thorough explanation.

Comment: This is probably a really simple issue but I am getting an error in the SQL query where you remove menuItemIds  <-----  Saying it doesn't exist in the current context.

    !menuItemIds.Contains
    menuItemIds.Except